# Grouping in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-2013

I am trying to sum the actual revenue, grouped by the sales person and then divide that value by the group-wide revenue target to get a 'percentage of total'

I have a database value for the salesperson (referred to as SAM below)

I thought I could create a formula field for SAM and then use it in another formula field such as

```
SUM({@Q1 Actuals},{@SAMFormula}) / SUM(@Q1 Target},{@Sectorcode})
```

But I get an error 'There must be a group that matches this field'

I'm wondering how to rectify this error?

Comment: Either `@SAMFormula` or `@Sectorcode` doesn't exist in report, create the group and then check

Comment: Thank you @Siva you are quite right. I had to INSERT > GROUP > SAMFormula and then suppress the group, after that it worked. I thought that just by having the source of that value dropped onto a grouping header it would work, but apparently not.